# I want to add a pair of EditTexts to RelativeLayout programmatically, on click of a button

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview, android-relativelayout

The first set of edittexts gets added neatly one below another, but on click of the button again, the views are getting overlapped. I think I need to set margins properly, but I am not able to figure it out. Please help.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    Button btn_task, btn_subTask;
    EditText et_task, et_subTask;
    RelativeLayout lv_subtask, lv_task;
    int i = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn_task = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_addTask);
        btn_subTask = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_subTask);
        lv_subtask = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.lv_subtask);
        lv_task = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.lv_task);

        // btn_task.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn_subTask.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (v.equals(btn_subTask)) {
            EditText et_title = new EditText(this);
            EditText et_date = new EditText(this);
            i++;
            et_title.setId(i);
            et_date.setId(i + 1);
            et_title.setHint("Enter sub task");
            et_date.setHint("Enter end date");
            // lv_subtask.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams EditLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams DateLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            DateLayoutParams.setMargins(5, 10, 0, 0);
            EditLayoutParams.setMargins(5, 20, 0, 0);
            if (i != 1) {
                EditLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, i + 1);
                DateLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, i + 2);

            } else {
                DateLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, 1);
            }
            et_title.setLayoutParams(EditLayoutParams);
            et_date.setLayoutParams(DateLayoutParams);
            (lv_subtask).addView(et_title);
            (lv_subtask).addView(et_date);

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: why you are not adding any `Rule` to `EditLayoutParams` in `else` statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like you are using your counter correctly. For one thing, you are only incrementing it by 1 each time onClick is called, but you are adding 2 views. Also, when you try to put the new views below the previous ones, you are **adding** to your counter, which would refer to IDs that you have not yet set. Try this:

```
if (v.equals(btn_subTask)) {
    EditText et_title = new EditText(this);
    EditText et_date = new EditText(this);
    et_title.setId(++i); // 1, 3, ...
    et_date.setId(++i); // 2, 4, ...
    et_title.setHint("Enter sub task");
    et_date.setHint("Enter end date");
    // lv_subtask.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams EditLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams DateLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    DateLayoutParams.setMargins(5, 10, 0, 0);
    EditLayoutParams.setMargins(5, 20, 0, 0);
    if (i != 2) {
        EditLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, i - 2); // below last view added
    }
    DateLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, i - 1); // always below current edit
    et_title.setLayoutParams(EditLayoutParams);
    et_date.setLayoutParams(DateLayoutParams);
    (lv_subtask).addView(et_title);
    (lv_subtask).addView(et_date);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For two Edittexts to magically appear have the EditTexts hidden in the layout and then make them visible in the OnClick for the button.  The trick is when your designing these they are always visible and you hide them when the app starts.

Define a boolean for visibility then in onResume you use the boolean to set the visibility.

```
  boolean ismyedittextvisible = false;


 public void onResume();
     super.onResume();
     view.findViewById(R.id.myedittext)
                .setVisibility(ismyedittextvisible ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
```

in your button onClick() toogle the value of the boolean and refresh the visisbility

```
@Override
public void onClick(final View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.mybutton) {
        ismyedittextvisisble = !ismyedittextvisible;
        view.findViewById(R.id.myedittext)
                .setVisibility(ismyedittextvisible ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But I guess this would be helpful in case where I need to views just once. But here I will be adding pair of edit texts, every time button is clicked.